# How to build single pipeline with multiple estimators supporting fit and predict?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a ML problem where I want to divide the prediction task into subproblems (where I believe specialized models will do better). All these predictions tasks operate independently and will use the same input data - but will have different estimators/targets.

**For example:**

- single dataset (A)
- shared transformations A -> B
- estimator #1: random forests with target Y1
- estimator #2: GBM classifier with target Y2
- estimator #3: logistic regression with target Y2
- the predictions of each of these models will be output as a tuple (#1, #2, #3)

**I'm looking for** a simple (or best practice way) to define the above pipeline and train it and be able to use it for prediction. I have looked at sklearn Pipeline but best I can tell you can't use that to have multiple estimators for training/predictions (would love to learn I'm wrong on this).

**My fallback option** is to build a class that supports `fit` and `predict_proba` but under the hood just calls these models sequentially (training in sequence & generating predictions in sequence before returning the tuple of results).

Is there a better way to go about this problem?

Comment: Relevant answers I have since found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275487/using-different-features-for-the-same-estimator-in-the-pipeline

Comment: And also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400722/feature-selection-for-multilabel-classification-scikit-learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scikit-learn pipelines are designed to chain operations, they are not designed to handle conditional logic.

Your problem is better handled in Python-based logic. Something like:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble      import GradientBoostingClassifier, RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model  import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline      import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


pipe_1 = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RandomForestClassifier())
pipe_2 = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), GradientBoostingClassifier())
pipe_3 = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression())

pipe_1.fit(X, y1)
pipe_2.fit(X, y2)
pipe_3.fit(X, y2)

predictions = (pipe_1.predict(X), pipe_2.predict(X), pipe_3.predict(X))
```

Comment: Thanks Brian - I was hoping I could feed MultiOutputClassifier a pipeline that contained a chain of operations - eg. normalization > feature selection > classifier. Do you know if that is possible - such that your example above could be simplified & optimized with the use of Parallel within MultiOutputClassifier?